# EF return null for some but EF Core return 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I migrate a site ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET MVC core, with EF to EF Core.

I make a request with empty value :

```
 var q = bd.Prod
           .Where(o => o.xxx == yyy)
           .GroupBy(o => o.sss)
           .Select(g => new
           {
               ccc = g.Key,
               vvv = g.Sum(i => i.qqq),
               bbb = g.Sum(i => i.fff),
               nnn = g.Sum(i => i.ggg),
           });
```

When I execute this code with EF return null when all cell of sum are empty. But EF Core return 0 when all cell of sum are empty. 
How to make EF Core return null ?

Comment: Blame them :) https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2410716-result-of-sum-of-an-empty-set-should-be-0-rather

Comment: Currently no luck, because EF Core processes `GroupBy` in memory (so called client evaluation), and this is known behavior of LINQ To Objects `Sum` implementation. Wait for EF Core v.2 to get that *eventually* fixed.

Comment: @grek40 Almost: it's not the sum of an empty set here, it's the sum of `null`s. The `null`s are discarded, and what remains is an empty set, but that's not the only possible reasonable behaviour when faced with `null`.

Comment: @hvd But that's the behavior of SQL `SUM` function - it returns `NULL` when the set is empty or all the values are `NULL`.

Comment: @IvanStoev I think I remember reading that EF Core would default to matching the L2O behaviour, and a special option would be needed to get the SQL behaviour. Same as how `a == b` can return true in EF when `a` and `b` are both `null`. The C# to SQL translation is not always straightforward.

Comment: @hvd That makes sense:) Unfortunately people coming from SQL (and EF6) would expect the SQL behavior by default (I guess). EF Core client evaluation is an evil - I personally prefer EF6 `NotSupported` exceptions :)

Comment: @IvanStoev To be clear, I didn't mean client evaluation, I meant it would (in a future version) by default translate to something like `ISNULL(SUM(...), 0)` just to make the behaviour match L2O's. Client evaluation is already something you can disable in EF Core.

Comment: @hvd Got it - crystal clear: they will replicate (by default) the (wrong) L2O behavior `null + null == 0` :) Hope at least they will provide some equivalent of `UseDatabaseNullSemantics` option. I do mention client evaluation because IMO it's the root of all such design decisions - to favor L2O behavior in case you don't disable it, and practically you can't disable it because SQL translation is not implemented yet for many query constructs perfectly supported in EF6. But you can't use EF6 with ASP.NET Core...

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DefaultIfEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var q = bd.Prod
          .Where(o => o.xxx == yyy)
          .GroupBy(o => o.sss)
          .Select(g => new
          {
            ccc = g.Key,
            vvv = g.Sum(i => i.qqq),
            bbb = g.Sum(i => i.fff),
            nnn = g.Sum(i => i.ggg),
         })
          .DefaultIfEmpty(null);
```

Comment: The OP explicitly mentions values of 0 as the current unwanted result. `DefaultIfEmpty` affects whether any items are returned at all. In other words, this will have zero effect for the OP. There was already a comment pointing this out. It's still true, and it still needs to be pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the following:

- Empty collection -> `null`
- Only `null` values -> `null`
- Any combination of numbers and `null` values -> number

Try this code:

```
items.Aggregate((int?)null, (acc, item) => acc.HasValue ? acc + item.GetValueOrDefault() : item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @grek40's answer for EF Core 5.0, you can create an extension method so that it can be re-used easily

```
public static decimal? SumOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, decimal?> selector)
    => (from s in source select selector(s))
       .Aggregate((decimal?)null, (acc, item) => acc.HasValue ? acc + item.GetValueOrDefault() : item);
```

or if you prefer any nulls to result in a null value

```
   public static decimal? SumAllOrNull<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, decimal?> selector)
        => (from s in source select selector(s))
           .Aggregate((decimal?)null, (acc, item) => acc.HasValue ? acc + item : item.HasValue ? item : null);
```

and then call it such as

```
var q = bd.Prod
           .Where(o => o.xxx == yyy)
           .GroupBy(o => o.sss)
           .Select(g => new
           {
               ccc = g.Key,
               vvv = g.SumOrDefault(i => i.qqq),
               bbb = g.SumOrDefault(i => i.fff),
               nnn = g.SumAllOrNull(i => i.ggg),
           });
```

Note: This only works on Linq-To-Objects, so if on DB query you must call .ToList() or AsIEnumerable before hand, until EF Core supports a way to do this in Linq-To-Sql